# Data structures (C): big bricks small house, or small bricks big house?

Tags: c, data-structures, organization

Suppose I have a C-library for building a `house` out of `brick`s. Associated with each `brick` is a set of `double`s and `int`s corresponding to its dimensions, weight, colour, and which shipment it came from, etc. A `house` is then just some form of organised collection of bricks. Some of the functions in my house-building library receive a `house`, but most of them receive and operate on `bricks`; the `house` is built mostly using local `brick`-wise operations corresponding to local changes like adding/removing a brick.

To my (feeble, inexperienced) mind, there are two `natural' ways to represent this `house`-made-of-`brick`s setup in terms of data structures.

**Approach 1: big transparent bricks, small house**. Have each `brick` structure contain fields for each of the associated `double`s and `int`s associated with it, plus pointers to the bricks immediately adjacent to it. In this setup, each `brick` is a large structure compared with the `house` (the `house` could conceivably just be a pointer to a any `brick`), and the whole thing is just a big web of pointers.

**Approach 2: small opaque bricks, big house**. Have each `brick` consist of an integer `index` and a pointer to its owning `house` only; the `house` then contains arrays of `double`s and `int`s into which the `brick`s can slice to get at their data, plus a few extra arrays/tables for all the connectivity information. With this approach, resources are held and managed using a large `house` structure which is visible to every `brick`, no matter where we are in the code.

**Question:** under what circumstances (if any) is Approach 1 preferable to Approach 2?

I have a strong preference for Approach 2, but struggle to articulate exactly what it is that makes it objectively *better* than Approach 1. Thanks in advance for any advice and/or pointers to appropriate reading material. Suggestions about how I can articulate my question better are also very welcome :)

Comment: Approach 1 is what's called a linked list, look it up. As to which approach is better suited for the job, it depends. Linked lists are usually used because they are very easily manipulated, resized, (re)moved, ...

Comment: Approach 2 sounds like a case of premature optimization. You may end up with compact arrays/lists of numbers in the memory, but otherwise it is unclear why a house should store data about its bricks.

Comment: @bool3max: I'm inclined to think of it as being more like a `web' than a 'list', but I take your point.

Comment: I find this question somewhat related to storing a graph in memory.
There are 2 approaches to storing graphs in memory:
1.each node gets a linked list containing all the indexes of the nodes it is adjacent to or
2.they are all stored in a huge matrix (called ["adjacency matrix"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix))
I hope you can see how it is related to your question.
Doing anything is faster with Approach 2 but it also requires way more memory(having ~100,000 nodes will get you out of memory). So using Approach 1 is preferred when Approach 2 uses too much memory.

Comment: @Dinu: graphs are one of the examples I had in mind when writing the question yes :)

Comment: @Ademi: that's a good point. I'm used to looking at the data from the perspective of someone constructing the house than someone asking questions about it after the fact. Your "...will be more representative of the problem you're trying to solve" is a nice turn of phrase.

Comment: You're overthinking all of this because you *haven't committed to writing code*. The sooner you try and apply all of this the sooner you'll understand the benefits and drawbacks of each.

Comment: @tadman: I've actually worked with both formats (and have my own ideas about each) but you're correct to assume that I've never been the one who decided which way things went.

Comment: Thought exercise: can you have a `house` without `brick`s? Can you have `brick`(s) without a `house`? The purpose of your application will dictate the abstraction of data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're describing a graph problem, and asking which method to represent this graph. However your question does not specify the application you're trying to implement. here is few scenarios came to mind:

1) The application is more concerned on the house than to every single brick: For example, you want to calculate certain metrics on the house , where most of the bricks are coming from, what's the final dimensions of the house, then the second approach will be more representative of the problem you're trying to solve. Hence easier implementation and maintenance.

2) It's crucial to treat and represent the bricks as independent entities. The application is more concerned on deleting,moving or more generally operating on a brick level instead of a house level. Then the first approach would be more suitable.

Comment: Whilst I agree with the general message here, I think my house-and-bricks setup occurs in a lot more contexts than representing graphs. Another example I have in mind is something like an abstract linear algebra library/module: here each 'brick' might be a vector or matrix and the containing `house' is some form of `workspace' containing all the matrix entries and some buffers for storing auxiliary variables and other bits and bobs needed for calculations without the caller of the module/library having to worry about memory management or other details to do with the internals of the module.

Comment: to be fair no problem is pure graph problem. I have faced similar kind of problem few months ago, where I was working on PDF files and in NLP context, a brick in this case could be a character and its colors positions fonts and so on, or an entire paragraph, while a house would be a paragraph, table, page or the entire document. My end solution was a hybrid approach of the two options you mention. with more implementation on the house level rather than the brick level.

Comment: Re. "My end solution was a hybrid approach of the two options you mention. with more implementation on the house level rather than the brick level", was that something you decided in advance or came around to gradually? If you were to do it again, would you do it the same way?

Comment: Well, it was a side project that """ I'm still working on """ stage. In its context I wanted to operate on entire sets of letters and paragraphs (AI recursive approaches), so since the start I new it's going to be a house approach implementation. However The challenge is to define what is a brick and which letters belong to which house, which required brick level operations, so the brick implementation grew with time

Answer (score 4):

You present two extremes, but there might be something inbetween that also works. For example, you can have the adjacency information stored in a house, but keep information about colour, weight, size and source in the brick. You can also move the source information out of both the house and brick structs, and put that into a separate struct, for example one that represents a source and which contains a list of pointers to bricks.

You cannot say objectively which approach is better until you say what goal you want to optimise for. Ademi already mentions two possible goals, but there might be more.
And then the question is also what parameter you want to optimise: is it performance? Code size? Runtime memory usage? Clarity of the code?

Once you have defined your goals, and you have two or more alternative implementations to choose from, you could try to implement all of them and then benchmark them. That will give you the most objective answer.

Comment: Thanks for this :) My main priority is usually just ease of use and ease of maintenance (taking it as a given that the thing has to actually work...)

Comment: If it's ease of maintenance, then I'd say go for the approach that requires the least amount of pointer/index fiddling to maintain consistency. As for ease of use for callers: it's easy in both approaches to add an API that hides the underlying details. If you want to write `house->add(brick)`, then that `add()` member function of `house` could update the ownership information regardless of whether it lives in `house` or `brick`. For example, if ownership information lives in brick then `House::add()` could internally call `brick->setOwner(this)`.